# Enabling Both HTTP and HTTPS for an Application in Tomcat 8

Tags: https, web.xml, tomcat8, server.xml, angular4-httpclient

I have one application deployed in Tomcat 8, which i want to run on http and https both. I have configured server.xml to run both on http and https. web.xml for application is also configured to handle both requests. Issue is i am getting response for https requests only. For http it says request timed out.

https port configured is 9999 and http port is 8080.
https://URL:9999/path  => working
http://URL:8080/path   => not working

Below is attached code for server.xml , web.xml inside WEB-INF directory and catalina.out response when i start Tomcat.

**SERVER.XML**

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       connectionTimeout="20000"/>
  <Connector
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       port="9999" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="/root/.keystore" keystorePass="Pooltooadm!n"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

**web.xml**

```
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>/index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>HTTP</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>HTTPS</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/index.html</location>
  </error-page>
```

**CATALINA.OUT=>**

```
17-Nov-2017 14:07:46.349 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
17-Nov-2017 14:07:46.433 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 28 2017 10:30:11 UTC
17-Nov-2017 14:07:46.593 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.23.0
17-Nov-2017 14:07:46.593 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
17-Nov-2017 14:07:46.593 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.4.21-90-default
17-Nov-2017 14:07:46.593 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
17-Nov-2017 14:07:46.593 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre
17-Nov-2017 14:07:46.594 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_151-b12
17-Nov-2017 14:07:46.594 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
17-Nov-2017 14:07:46.594 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.23
17-Nov-2017 14:07:46.594 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.23
17-Nov-2017 14:07:46.594 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/conf/logging.properties
17-Nov-2017 14:07:46.595 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
17-Nov-2017 14:07:46.595 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
17-Nov-2017 14:07:46.637 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
17-Nov-2017 14:07:46.637 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.23
17-Nov-2017 14:07:46.637 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.23
17-Nov-2017 14:07:46.637 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/temp
17-Nov-2017 14:07:46.637 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
17-Nov-2017 14:07:51.020 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
17-Nov-2017 14:07:51.711 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
17-Nov-2017 14:07:51.832 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-9999"]
17-Nov-2017 14:08:00.507 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
17-Nov-2017 14:08:00.509 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
17-Nov-2017 14:08:00.510 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
17-Nov-2017 14:08:00.592 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 28123 ms
17-Nov-2017 14:08:01.206 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
17-Nov-2017 14:08:01.207 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
17-Nov-2017 14:08:01.495 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/webapps/host-manager]
17-Nov-2017 14:08:11.450 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [159] milliseconds.
17-Nov-2017 14:08:12.311 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [10,816] ms
17-Nov-2017 14:08:12.312 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/webapps/manager]
17-Nov-2017 14:08:12.924 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/webapps/manager] has finished in [612] ms
17-Nov-2017 14:08:12.924 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/webapps/docs]
17-Nov-2017 14:08:13.415 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/webapps/docs] has finished in [491] ms
17-Nov-2017 14:08:13.415 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/webapps/ROOT]
17-Nov-2017 14:08:13.825 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [409] ms
17-Nov-2017 14:08:13.825 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/webapps/examples]
17-Nov-2017 14:08:20.096 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/webapps/examples] has finished in [6,271] ms
17-Nov-2017 14:08:20.097 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/webapps/pooltooadmin]
17-Nov-2017 14:08:20.549 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/webapps/pooltooadmin] has finished in [451] ms
17-Nov-2017 14:08:20.836 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
17-Nov-2017 14:08:20.999 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-9999"]
17-Nov-2017 14:08:21.163 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
17-Nov-2017 14:08:21.204 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 20612 ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to this by configuring web.xml as follows:-

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Support Both HTTP and HTTPS</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
       <!--   <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee> -->
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe port 8080 is taken already. If you have apache2 on your server the default port for apache2 is 8080. Try another port or check:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn |grep apache
```

Comment: I have checked with netstat and the port 8080 is indeed used by tomcat only.  Port 8080 is started only when i start the tomcat and is not accessible after shutting down the tomcat.

Comment: you can straight change the port value to another port i.e. port="8181". (edit server.xml as admin or you might get access denies error)

Comment: This will change the default port for Tomcat. Another option is to run your http version on another port if you don't want to change your default settings of tomcat

Comment: Port is changed successfully but issue persists. http still not working. Is there anything to do with web.xml configuration?? I have commented out **<transport-guarantee>** tag in the file. web resource name tag is configured as **<web-resource-name>Support Both HTTP and HTTPS</web-resource-name>**

Comment: was able to achieve by changing web.xml for application.